# How to change message before abandon

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'd like to change a message property before abandoning. The following code don't work. I'm receiving the message with the initial Label.

```
message.Label = "failed";
message.Abandon();
```

It it possible to define that message was abandoned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update content of an Azure Service Bus Queue message object. Frankly, if I have to update a message content, than there is something wrong in my approach.

You can, however, update the content of an [Azure Storage Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue_methods.aspx) message, using the [UpdateMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.updatemessage.aspx) method or any of its async friends. In any case, I feel wrong the general approach of touching message content!

For your purpose I suggest that you take a look at [DeadLetterQueue](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-Dead-22536dd8) feature of Azure SErvice Bus Queues and Topics, or the [DequeueCount property of Azure Storage message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudqueuemessage.dequeuecount) to determine whether there is something wrong with the message.

Comment: Something to add to @astaykov's answer is that you can modify/update the Properties of a service bus message when you abandon it.  There is an overload of Abandon that takes an IDictionary<String, Object> that can be used to set a property.  In this case you could set a property that could help the next processor that picks it up to have an idea of why it was abandoned. Remember that a message could end up with a dequeue count for failures you aren't able to control as well and I also think the dead letter queue is a good idea if you know it has failed.

Comment: There is (as of Feb 1st, 2022) *actually* an open issue to support the idea of abandoning a message while setting, not just user properties, but also a new scheduled enqueue time for delaying reprocessing of the message, instead of having it retry immediately over and over until it deadletters: https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/454  The original thread also mentions a workaround of using service bus transactions to atomically schedule a new message while completing the old one; which would work similarly.